# WEBRTC peer connection blocked by UAE?

Tags: networking, webrtc

I have implemented basic WEBRTC peer connection between two clients and uses RTCPeerConnection and getUserMedia APIs for it. I am fetching Audio tracks only from the stream.

Even though my signalling works, ice agents are shared, streams are shared as well.

The audio comes out distorted completely.

However, if I utilize a VPN on one device the other device can hear the audio coming from the device with VPN very clearly with no hiccups.

NOTE:

I tried this with only stun and with a combination of stun and turn servers(viagenie).

Can someone tell me how do i debug the issue, what to look for?

Is my ISP involved in messing around with the media stream? (I live in the UAE.)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think the problem is UAE ISP block the STUN/TURN PORT (3478,5766 ...)

you can try to use 443/80 port?

Comment: I was using google stun servers and viagenie as turn server but now i made my own coturn server on digital ocean and made the server listen on port 80 and connection is stable now.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. I have deployed my own server with port 443 still webrtc calls to UAE are not working whereas it works in other countries. any help would be appreciated.